# Django: Get a list of all related objects in models.py

Tags: python, django, django-models

it's a stupid question but i'm new to django and I didn't find a answer so far.

I'm trying to get a list of all related Years in the get_savings function.
Don't look at the attributes of Year and Plan. They all exist.
The focus is on the For loop. I also tried `for year in self.year_set.all:` but it didn't work either.

**models.py**

```
class Plan(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...

    @property
    def get_saving(self):
        delta: timedelta = now() - self.date_created
        months_gone = delta.days / 30
        saving = 0
        for year in Year.objects.all():
            if months_gone > year.months:
                saving = saving + year.savings_year
            else:
                saving = saving + months_gone * year.income_month
        return saving


class Year(models.Model):
    title = models.IntegerField()
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: i edited in the second place, check your original, may be you have two typo.

Comment: Although you said you've tried to use the reverse relationship, you've missed the parenthesis there. You _should_ be able to use `self.year_set.all()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.year_set.all()` is what you need.

all is a function so you need to call it rather than just reference it.

Comment: @BearBrown - Nope, guessing thats a typo where the `:` should be a `=`

Comment: @BearBrown yes it was xD